# When to use Ambient occlusion in Blender Render?

Tags: texturing

Quote from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/what-is-ambient-occlusion)

> So in cycles there often is no need for it.

So there must be a need for it in Blender Render

Can you think of a scenario where using ambient occlusion in Blender Render mode is the better choice over the other available option like spot lamps and nodes?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7816/what-is-ambient-occlusion and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14198/whats-the-purpose-of-ambient-occlusion-node-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51751/emphasizing-cycles-render-ambient-occlusion/51809#51809

Comment: It can be used in a stylized render to increase the contrast in shadows; it's an effect that makes things look better.

Comment: @shady puck, but cant you do all of that with lamps alone?

Comment: AO is used to make things look more photorealsitic, it takes in account for  other objects in the scene making better shadows and lighting, reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbWV58AH9eg

Comment: @sammy but dont regular lamps do a better job at that? The manual says that "There is no such thing as AO in real life"

Comment: maybe only use it if you have a slow computer and cant afford to use a lamp?

Comment: Same question just minutes apart http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57878/ambient-occlusion-vs-environment-lighting

Comment: no, this question doesnt mention environmental lighting. It is different.

Comment: IMHO - it adds a sense of realistic dirtiness to things that get closer together. It is algorithmic, and not physically based (hence it is not something you can even do by lighting). This being said however, there is a flip side to this as well. You can also lift your lightness of values in cases where lights trying to do the work would either be very noisy or simply not bright enough (GPU/CPU BOUNCE INTENSIVE). So between not wanting to spend to much time on applying unnecessary dirt maps, or fighting with my lighting & render times, it's a pretty slick way to sell realism on the cheap.

Comment: so use it to simulate dirt in crevices?

Comment: It looks like the best place to use AO is in Blender Render to simulate it being in Cycles.

Comment: @eromod Maybe, but as I said, it _can_ be used. It's just an effect. Just you might use post processing tools in the compositor to change the color channels or distort the lens. You don't need the compositor. It simply enhances your image.

Comment: I know that it can be used, im trying to figure out a good scenario to use it.

Comment: example of usage : your model is to be used with another rendering system (game or other) which does not handle AO/lights/shadows efficiently. It can also enforce the apparent geometry of a low poly model.